# notification with pushsharp

Tags: pushsharp

I want to implement notification in web application with pushsharp.

I found some sample projects on github for pushspharp they are working.

please help me in getting start to develop small app on notifications with pushsharp.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

public class PushNotificationService
    {
        private PushService _pushService;

```
    public string MessageDetails { get; set; }
   // public RecipientDeliveryStatus MessageDeliveryStatus { get; set; }

    public PushNotificationService()
    {
        _pushService = new PushService();
        _pushService.Events.OnDeviceSubscriptionExpired += Events_OnDeviceSubscriptionExpired;
        _pushService.Events.OnDeviceSubscriptionIdChanged += Events_OnDeviceSubscriptionIdChanged;
        _pushService.Events.OnChannelException += Events_OnChannelException;
        _pushService.Events.OnNotificationSendFailure += Events_OnNotificationSendFailure;
        _pushService.Events.OnNotificationSent += Events_OnNotificationSent;
        _pushService.Events.OnChannelCreated += Events_OnChannelCreated;
        _pushService.Events.OnChannelDestroyed += Events_OnChannelDestroyed;

    }

    public void SendAppleNotification(string deviceToken, string message)
    {
        var appleCert = File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "../../../Resources/PushSharp.Apns.Sandbox.p12"));
        _pushService.StartApplePushService(new ApplePushChannelSettings(appleCert, "pushsharp"));
        _pushService.QueueNotification(NotificationFactory.Apple()
         .ForDeviceToken(deviceToken)
         .WithAlert(message)
         .WithSound("default")
         .WithBadge(7));
        _pushService.StopApplePushService();

    }


    public void SendAndroidNotification(string message, string deviceRegId)
    {
        _pushService.StartGoogleCloudMessagingPushService(new GcmPushChannelSettings("Config.AnrodidSenderId", "Config.AndroidAuthToken", "Config.AndroidApplicationId"));

        _pushService.QueueNotification(NotificationFactory.AndroidGcm()
                                           .ForDeviceRegistrationId(deviceRegId)
                                           .WithCollapseKey("NONE")
                                 .WithJson("{\"alert\":\"" + message + "\",\"badge\":\"7\"}"));
        _pushService.StopGoogleCloudMessagingPushService();
    }


    public void SendWindowsNotification()
    {
        _pushService.StartWindowsPhonePushService(new WindowsPhonePushChannelSettings());
        //Configure and start Windows Notifications
        _pushService.StartWindowsPushService(new WindowsPushChannelSettings("677AltusApps.PushSharpTest",
            "ms-app://s-1-15-2-397915024-884168245-3562497613-3307968140-4074292843-797285123-433377759", "ei5Lott1HEbbZBv2wGDTUsrCjU++Pj8Z"));

        //Fluent construction of a Windows Toast Notification
        _pushService.QueueNotification(NotificationFactory.Windows().Toast().AsToastText01("This is a test").ForChannelUri("YOUR_CHANNEL_URI_HERE"));
        _pushService.StopWindowsPhonePushService();
    }
    void Events_OnDeviceSubscriptionIdChanged(PlatformType platform, string oldDeviceInfo, string newDeviceInfo, Notification notification)
    {

      //  MessageDeliveryStatus = RecipientDeliveryStatus.Undeliverable;
        MessageDetails = "Device subscription id has changed";
    }

    void Events_OnNotificationSent(Notification notification)
    {

        //MessageDeliveryStatus = RecipientDeliveryStatus.Sent;
        MessageDetails = "Message Sent";
    }

    void Events_OnNotificationSendFailure(Notification notification, Exception notificationFailureException)
    {

        //MessageDeliveryStatus = RecipientDeliveryStatus.Undeliverable;
        MessageDetails = notificationFailureException.Message;
    }

    void Events_OnChannelException(Exception exception, PlatformType platformType, Notification notification)
    {

       // MessageDeliveryStatus = RecipientDeliveryStatus.Undeliverable;
        MessageDetails = exception.Message;
    }

    void Events_OnDeviceSubscriptionExpired(PlatformType platform, string deviceInfo, Notification notification)
    {

       // MessageDeliveryStatus = RecipientDeliveryStatus.Undeliverable;
        MessageDetails = "Device Subscription Expired";
    }

    void Events_OnChannelDestroyed(PlatformType platformType, int newChannelCount)
    {
       // MessageDeliveryStatus = RecipientDeliveryStatus.Undeliverable;
        MessageDetails = "Channel Descrtroyed";
    }

    void Events_OnChannelCreated(PlatformType platformType, int newChannelCount)
    {
        //MessageDeliveryStatus = RecipientDeliveryStatus.Undeliverable;
        MessageDetails = "Channel Created";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a .net 3.5 application and I needed to use `PushSharp`, so I ended up creating a `WebApi` wrapper around pushSharp so that it can be consumed just as a simple `RESTful` api.

I have put the code on GitHub in case anybody needs it. `PushSharp.Web`

https://github.com/has-taiar/PushSharp/tree/master/PushSharp.Web